# Template format error: YAML not well-formed

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm getting `Template format error: YAML not well-formed` on the final line of this resource but no idea where I'm going wrong.

```
  LambdaPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Join
        - ''
        - - !Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:'
          - Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub ${ParentStack}-api
          - '/*'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a tab after `ImportValue`.

```
  LambdaPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !Join
        - ''
        - - !Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:'
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub ${ParentStack}-api
          - '/*'
```

Comment: That's two spaces, not a tab. A tab would not work because YAML doesn't accept tabs for indentation.